# Why copy constructor, operator= and reference in this class have compile issue

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I tried to search for solution but found nothing. If this is a duplicated question, I apologize in advance.

I have a class like this:

```
class sync_lock {
    public:
        enum lock_status { free, locked };
        pthread_cond_t cond;
        pthread_mutex_t mtx;
        lock_status status;

        sync_lock() : status(free) {
            pthread_cond_init( &cond, NULL );
            pthread_mutex_init( &mtx, NULL );
        }

        sync_lock(const sync_lock & param) {
            cond = param.cond;
            mtx = param.mtx;
            status = param.status;
        }

        sync_lock & operator=(const sync_lock & param) {
            if (this == &param)
                return *this;
            cond = param.cond;
            mtx = param.mtx;
            status = param.status;
            return *this;
        }

        ~sync_lock() {
            pthread_cond_destroy( &cond );
            pthread_mutex_destroy( &mtx );
        }
};
```

And in the driver code, I have this:

```
line 29: sync_lock lock();
line 30: lock_map[lid] = lock;
```

Another place has this:

```
line 33: sync_lock & lock = lock_map[lid];
```

When I compile, I got this:

```
lock_server.cc: In member function ‘lock_protocol::status lock_server::acquire(int, lock_protocol::lockid_t, int&)’:
lock_server.cc:30:25: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((lock_server*)this)->lock_server::lock_map.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = long long unsigned int, _Tp = sync_lock, _Compare = std::less<long long unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const long long unsigned int, sync_lock> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = sync_lock, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = long long unsigned int]((*(const key_type*)(& lid))) = lock’
lock_server.cc:30:25: note: candidate is:
lock_server.h:33:21: note: sync_lock& sync_lock::operator=(const sync_lock&)
lock_server.h:33:21: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘sync_lock()’ to ‘const sync_lock&’
make: *** [lock_server.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea what caused this error. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
sync_lock lock();
```

Does not do what you think it does.  You are expecting it to declare a variable named `lock` of type `sync_lock` that is default-constructed.  It actually declares a parameter-less function named `lock` that returns a `sync_lock` instance.  The reason for that is known as [**most vexing parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Thus, when you then assign `lock` to `lock_map[lid]` without parenthesis on `lock`, you are actually assigning a function pointer, not a `sync_lock` instance.  That is why you are getting a conversion error instead of invoking the `=` operator.

The fix is to simply drop the parenthesis on the variable declaration:

```
sync_lock lock;
```

Or, get rid of the variable altogether:

```
lock_map[lid] = sync_lock();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was about to write a comment but it became too long.

This kind of classes should not be copyable.

Lets take a look to the destructor:

```
~sync_lock() {
    pthread_cond_destroy( &cond );
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &mtx );
}
```

It will destroy the `mutex` and the `condition`, invalidating any copy of the object you have.

This line:

```
lock_map[lid] = sync_lock();
```

Will do the following:

1. Create a temporary object (indexing operator)
2. Create another temporary object (call to `sync_lockl()`)
3. Call assignment operator in the first object (point `(1)`)
4. Destroy the object created in `(2)`

The consequences of this procedure are disastrous:

1. The `mutex` and the `condition` initialized in point `(1)` will never get destroyed because they were overwritten by the assignment operator
2. If the code had the following format:

```
    {
        sync_lock lock; // line 29
        lock_map[lid] = lock; // line 30
    } // line 31
```

The `mutex` and `condition` created in `line 29` will be destroyed after `line 31`, when `lock`'s destructor gets called.

Si, my advice, ***never make classes having this kind of resources copyable***, specially when dealing with synchronization objects. If you want to put them in a container, fine, but use a pointer.

With C++11 you can make them movable, that will solve most of the problems of the current solution, but C++ also has `std::mutex` and `std::condition` so maybe you can rely on them instead of `pthread`.

Update: Based on the `std::map` implementation in GCC 4.7 (optimizations aside)

```
  mapped_type&
  operator[](const key_type& __k)
  {
// concept requirements
__glibcxx_function_requires(_DefaultConstructibleConcept<mapped_type>)

iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
// __i->first is greater than or equivalent to __k.
if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
      // inserts new object
      __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
return (*__i).second;
  }
```

Comment: Assigning to the `[]` operator will not create a temporary. If `id` does not exist yet, it will be created and added to the `map`. That is probably the temporary you are thinking of. But the `[]` operator returns a reference, so `=` is called on the original `sync_lock` that exists in the `map`. And RVO might optimize away the temporary that `syck_lock()` returns. But you are right that a copyable lock is dangerous. A movable lock, on the other hand, makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, just added a clarification.

Comment: Hi ichram, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! I used your solution, use pointer.